# Laravel Scheduler Running multiple time

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, homestead

I'm Using Laravel 5.6

In that, I'm running Laravel In Homestead with Scheduler

I Have configured scheduler in Homestead.yaml file like this

```
- map: demo.test
  to: /home/vagrant/sites/project/public
  schedule: true
```

In Side of App\Console\Kernal.php I'm running this code

```
$schedule->call(function (){
   \Log::info('works');
})->at('18:34');
```

I'm getting Output three-time ??? with 4 second delay

```
[2019-03-12 18:34:04] local.INFO: works  
[2019-03-12 18:34:04] local.INFO: works  
[2019-03-12 18:34:04] local.INFO: works
```

Expected Output one time.

```
[2019-03-12 18:34:00] local.INFO: works
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the right log? It's been logged at `17:55:33` and your scheduler is between `17:00` and `17:02`.

Comment: Output is just an example don't worry about that

Comment: Can you give us the real log with the real time? It's hard to find the reason with an `example` where every second matters.

Comment: I have updated the real log.

Answer (score 0):

`between` is an inclusive function, which means it would run at 17:00, 17:01, and 17:02. If you want it to run once at a specific time, use `at()`

```
$schedule->call(function (){
   \Log::info('works');
})->at('17:01');
```

Comment: It's not related to time, i can put time like 17:00 and 17:25 still output is coming there time.

Comment: I have also tried vagrant reload --provision and then vagrant ssh